# The ResultSet can not be null for Statement.executeQuery

Tags: java, mysql, exception, resultset

I am inserting data to a MySQL DB, but get an error, when executing the insert statement:

> The ResultSet can not be null for Statement.executeQuery.

Although if i check the database table, I find that the values have been successfully inserted. This is confusing.

**Code Snippet**

```
Connection connection = null;
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:google:rdbms://name-of-instance");
Statement check = connection.createStatement();
java.sql.ResultSet resultset = null;
resultset = check.executeQuery("insert into table_name values (values-inserted-here);");
```

Answer (score 1):

To execute queries that update, delete or insert any data in your DB, you cannot use [`executeQuery(String sql)` (check here the docs)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery%28java.lang.String%29), but [`executeUpdate(String sql)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String)) instead.

So instead of:

```
check.executeQuery("insert into table_name values (values-inserted-here);");
```

You should do:

```
check.executeUpdate("insert into table_name values (values-inserted-here);");
```

The `ResultSet` is always null in an insert, delete or update, that is why it was giving you that error. If you use `executeUpdate` the error should be gone.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

No need to use ResultSet.
ResultSet only used when you fetch data from query like select query.
Just use

```
Statement check = connection.createStatement();
check.executeUpdate("insert into table_name values (values-inserted-here)");
```

and for tutorial use this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-insert-records.htm)